# How to merge print_area from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I found a code that merge multiple sheets of workbook. It's run smoothly, but I just want merge only `Range("Print_Area")` of multiple sheets, please help me how to fix

```
Sub MergeSheets()        
    Const NHR = 1

    Dim MWS As Worksheet 
    Dim AWS As Worksheet 
    Dim FAR As Long 
    Dim LR As Long

    Set AWS = ActiveSheet

    For Each MWS In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets 
        If Not MWS Is AWS Then
            FAR = AWS.UsedRange.Cells(AWS.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row + 1
            LR = MWS.UsedRange.Cells(MWS.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row        
            MWS.Range(MWS.Rows(NHR + 1), MWS.Rows(LR)).Copy AWS.Rows(FAR)
        End If
    Next MWS 
End Sub
```

Comment: Then just copy that range. `MWS.Range("Print_Area").Copy AWS.Rows(FAR)` Where is the issue?

Comment: it's run. Thank you